# MessageBox C++. Проблема с выводом строки

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, messagebox

Мне нужно в MessageBox запихнуть string. На выходе я получаю не нужную строку, а набор китайских иероглифов.

```
string str = enterStr();

wsprintf(_buffer, TEXT("%s"), str.c_str());

MessageBox(
    NULL,
    _buffer,
    TEXT("info"),
    MB_OK
);
```

Функция возвращает нужную строку типа string.

Comment: А зачем вам тут `wsprintf`? Выводите сразу `str`: ```MessageBoxA(NULL, str.c_str(), TEXT("info"), MB_OK);``` Не надо конвертировать строки без надобности.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы печатаете юникодную (UCS-2) строку, но на вход подаете обычный ASCII. В результате у вас  каждая пара ASCII символов дает символ юникода где-то в районе иероглифов. Лечится просто - печатайте ASCII, для этого достаточно в `wsprintf` заменить `%s` на `%S`:

```
wsprintf(_buffer, TEXT("%S"), str.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

Я конечно не знаю используете ли Вы `MessageBoxA` (для ASCII) или `MessageBoxW` (для мультибайта), и что у Вас в строке, но вот этот код выводит русский текст в оконном сообщении:

```
#include "windows.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#define SOURCE_CHARSET 65001 // UTF8

std::wstring string_to_wstring(std::string str){
    std::wstring convertedString;
    int requiredSize = MultiByteToWideChar(SOURCE_CHARSET, 0, str.c_str(), -1, 0, 0);
    if( requiredSize > 0 ){
        std::vector<wchar_t> buffer(requiredSize);
        MultiByteToWideChar(SOURCE_CHARSET, 0, str.c_str(), -1, &buffer[0], requiredSize);
        convertedString.assign(buffer.begin(), buffer.end() - 1);
    }
    return convertedString;
}

int main (){
    std::string str = "Привет, мир!";
    MessageBoxW(NULL, string_to_wstring(str).c_str(), L"Оконное сообшение", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);

    return 0;
}
```

У меня IDE в UTF8 файлы сохраняет. Если что, ASCII это `CP_ACP` он же `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш

```
string str = ...:

wsprintf(_buffer, TEXT("%s"), str.c_str());
```

это какая-то эклектическая каша из кусочков разных миров:

- Функция `wsprintf` - это функция, работающая строго с *широкими* символами.
- Литерал `TEXT("%s")` - это "полиморфный" литерал, который может быть широким или узком в зависимости от настроек проекта.
- Параметр `str.c_str()` - указатель на строго *узкую* строку.

Что это за мешанина? Когда вы принимали решение о том, в каких символах вы будете работать, что вы решили? Узкие? Широкие? "Полиморфные"?

Если это код у вас вообще компилируется, значит вы настроили свой проект на широкие символы и прямое использование `wsprintf` как бы намекает, что вы решили работать именно в *широких* символах. Тогда причем здесь вообще `TEXT("%s")`? `TEXT` предназначен для написания "полиморфного" кода, у вас же все жестко и однозначно завязано на широкие символы. Пишите прямо `L"%s"` безо всяких `TEXT`. Этот `TEXT` здесь совершенно не нужен и не уместен.

Но если вы решили работать именно в широких символах, то почему тогда вы используете `std::string`, а не `std::wstring`? Используйте `std::wstring` и все будет работать

```
wstring str = ...:

wsprintf(_buffer, L"%s", str.c_str());
```

И только если по какой-то веской посторонней причине вам вдруг нужно скрестить ужа и ежа, т.е. использовать здесь именно `std::string`, то тогда спецификатор формата в `wsprintf` должен быть `%S`, а не `%s`

```
string str = ...:

wsprintf(_buffer, L"%S", str.c_str());
```

Comment: мне нравитсья  ваша новая шляпа:)